# Livewire Search Users not working as expected

Tags: php, laravel

I was following the instructions given on the Livewire website to create a 'search users' input, that would have a text input, and right above it, list all the users, and as you write in the input, it should filter the users on the list. The problem is that the filter is not working (the list of users is displayed normally), and i have no idea why.. I've done this in other projects that i had, but on this one, it's simply not working..

My SearchUsers.php is this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\User;

class SearchUsers extends Component
{ 
    public $search = '';    

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.search-users', [
            'users' => User::where('name', 'like', '%' . $this->search . '%')->get()
        ]);
    }
}
```

And my search-users.blade.php is this:

```
<div>
    <input wire:model="search" type="text" placeholder="Search users..."/>

    <ul>
        @foreach($users as $user)
            <li>{{ $user->name }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
```

The list is loaded normally, the only problem is the filter.. I've already searched in many forums and websites, and found nothing, so any help will be appreciated!

Comment: What happens if you dont filter and just do a `->get()`? Do you get all users? If not then the problem is either how you fetch or how you display users. If you do get users, then the problem is the filter. Does `$this->search` have a value?

Comment: Not familiar on how components work but this should give you some insights how to debug.

Comment: The list of users is displayed normally, sorry, i edited the question to show this.. the problem is with the filter, that's not working at all

Comment: Did you check when you do your search, it passes through the render again? If yes, does the value `$this->search` has the correct value? I feel like you would need a constructor here to add the value in the component. But I could be wrong since I dont really use component.

Comment: I mean, i've followed it exactly as it said in the documentation so..

Comment: That was not the point. The point was to debug what is the problem in your code. That was why I said **I could be wrong since I dont use component**. Now did you check if `$this->search` has the correct value?

Comment: So, i solved the problem, it was a problem with the version of livewire. I was using 3.0 and now i've downgraded to 2.4, and now everything works, so i guess bad documentation..?